# want to generate multiple charts in d3 in same page for different data set

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am querying a database and adding the result in a json file and trying to generate charts for each records in a same page.

Here is my JSON data set(all the records in a single file) that I generated querying mySql database. Now I want to generate charts (bar or pie chart is enough )for each records. Is that possible?

```
[
//record1
    {"ProductType1":"999999","value1":"99"},
    {"ProductType1":"88888","value1":"88"},
    {"ProductType1":"77777","value1":"77"},
    {"ProductType1":"999999","value1":"99"},
//record 2
    {"ProductType":"132023","value":"144"},
    {"ProductType":"132030","value":"275"},
    {"ProductType":"132053","value":"42"},
    {"ProductType":"132093","value":"1"},
    {"ProductType":"132197","value":"94"},
//record 3
    {"ProductType2":"132207","value2":"23"},
    {"ProductType2":"304055","value2":"51"},
    {"ProductType2":"520002","value2":"27"},
    {"ProductType2":"522275","value2":"34"}
]

Or please suggest some other workarounds to get this done
```

Comment: can you just do a loop through them and create the pie charts?

Comment: Actually each records contains different key,value. Can I still loop through them and generate pie or bar chart? Actually I am new to D3, can you please direct me to some example?

Comment: pass the different key, value, dataset, svg container as parameters to a rendering function then

Comment: you may want to google "reusable d3.js charts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it by following steps.

- Create a key value map for your data array first.(You can dynamically  generate it from the data array if key value names has a regular pattern)

  `var keyMap = [{
    category: 'ProductType',
    value: 'value'
  }, {
    category: 'ProcessType',
    value: 'errorcount'
  }, {
    category: 'Message',
    value: 'count'
  }];`
- Convert the existing data in Array of Objects format to and Array of Arrays format.

  `var formattedData = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return Object.keys(d)[0]; })
      .entries(data)
      .map(function(d){ return d.values });`
- Once a key map is created, you can iterate over the data array and create charts as shown in below snippet.
- Calculate the chart positions as per the requirement inside the loop and place SVG accordingly.

Here is a sample code snippet.

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 155,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 3;

var keyMap = [{
  category: 'ProductType1',
  value: 'value1'
}, {
  category: 'ProductType',
  value: 'value'
}, {
  category: 'ProductType2',
  value: 'value2'
}];

var data =[
    {"ProductType1":"999999","value1":"99"},
    {"ProductType1":"88888","value1":"88"},
    {"ProductType1":"77777","value1":"77"},
    {"ProductType1":"999999","value1":"99"},
    {"ProductType":"132023","value":"144"},
    {"ProductType":"132030","value":"275"},
    {"ProductType":"132053","value":"42"},
    {"ProductType":"132093","value":"1"},
    {"ProductType":"132197","value":"94"},
    {"ProductType2":"132207","value2":"23"},
    {"ProductType2":"304055","value2":"51"},
    {"ProductType2":"520002","value2":"27"},
    {"ProductType2":"522275","value2":"34"}
];

var formattedData = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return Object.keys(d)[0]; })
.entries(data).map(function(d){ return d.values });

formattedData.forEach(function(pieData, i) {

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

  var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")    
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
      console.log(keyMap[i].value, d);
      return d[keyMap[i].value];
    });

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(pieData))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d, j) {
      return color(j);
    });

  g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {    
      return d.data[keyMap[i].category];
    });

  function type(d) {
    d[keyMap[i].value] = +d[keyMap[i].value];
    return d;
  }
});
```

```css
.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
div{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much Gilsha!

Comment: Hi Gilsha, Actually the data that you used is not in correct JSON format, actually the one updated in my question is the correct format. Can you please help me incorporating that data. I am loading the file externally and it is in correct JSON format but I am getting "i.map is not a function" error at line data.forEach(function(pieData, i). Please help me.

Comment: Hi Deena, I have updated the answer and fiddle. Hope it is helpful,

Comment: Thanks very much Gilsha!